# Isotope Dynamic Sorts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using the jQuery Isotope plugin (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which is awesome, but I have a problem with creating the sorts.  It's more of a JavaScript problem than anything to do with Isotope itself.

The problem is that I'm building the sort data dynamically.  So I've created a function that makes the sortData.  An example below:

```js
function getSortData(){
    sortData = {};
    var sorts = ['symbol', 'number', 'score', 'name'];
    for (var i in sorts) {
      sortData[sorts[i]] = function($elem) {
        console.log(sorts[i]);
        return parseInt($elem.find('.'+ sorts[i]).text());     
      }
    }
    return sortData;
  }
```

So the problem is that the anonymous function inside always runs after the entire getSortData() function has run.  Resulting in the last item in the sorts array being assigned to the sort[i] variable.

This is shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzZR4/
You'll see that the 'name' item is always outputted to the console.

I can't think of another way to create the getSortData object that will allow the correct sort name to be passed.

Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

What was really needed was to allow the sort field name variable to have local scope inside the anonymous sort function.  As I wasn't able to pass in the sort field directly into the anonymous function (as it's called by Isotope, so I can't control the parameters passed to it).

So the trick was to create another function that returned an anonymous function, this would take the field as an argument, making it have local scope.

```js
function getSortData(){
    sortData = {};
    var sorts = ['symbol', 'number', 'score', 'name'];
    var sortField;
    for (var i in sorts) {
      sortField = sorts[i];
      sortData[sortField] = getSortDataCallback(sortField)
    }
    return sortData;
  }

function getSortDataCallback(sortField) {
  return function($elem) {
    return parseInt($elem.find('.'+ sortField).text());
  }
}
```

Comment: And what has this to do with the last element inserted?

Comment: Chiyou what do you mean?  It's nothing to do with the last element inserted, it's about the sorts.

Comment: DO you mean in the fiddle?  I hadn't actually updated it.  Here's the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/sENdQ/

Comment: No, why do you need an anonymous function and a return function? I didn't see the return but can't you use do sort[i] = parseInt($elem.find.... ???

Comment: Because the sort[i] variable isn't local to the function, so when it's fired by Isotope it's value will always be the same for every type of sort (it will be the last item in the sorts array, as that's where it was left on).